# putting a comma and space between publisher and year in book type in customize bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have made a customize bibliography style file using [bst file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqwgNJHkwTrf13OMz9nOYjjdY-RR?e=GcTvWK).

For the books entry, I am getting the following output.

> F. Harary, **Graph Theory**, Addison-Wesley Publ. Comp., Reading, Massachusetts1969.

Instead I wish to have the entry

> F. Harary, **Graph Theory**, Addison-Wesley Publ. Comp., Reading, Massachusetts, 1969.

I am unable to locate the line to where I should change the commands and what command should I use.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OneDrive link appears to be broken.

Comment: Could you please check it now?

Comment: Now it works out fine

Comment: Please add a compilable cde using your bst file that shows the output you get, so far I am unable to compile a simple example with the bst of your link.